# RTMP video streaming for ios like (wowza media server)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, rtmp

I am working on video playing application which is support to play an video. I am implementing RTMP video streaming for iOS (i.e wowza media server). So please help me how to use this RTMP streaming for playing the video in ios6.